# My app gets rejected from Apple because it crashes on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Apple has rejected my app due to the following reasons:

1) We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

2) Your app crashed on launch on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

---

I'm running Xcode version 4.3.2, which isn't compatible with iPhone 5 i think, so i'm suggesting that my app rejected because i tested it in old Xcode version which doesn't support iPhone 5 architecture, right?

for the second reason Apple rejected my app i think because even my app doesn't use internet connection through the code i have to check the availability of internet connection on launch by taking advantage of Reachability library, right?

note that i tested my app on both simulator and actual devices all running iOS 5.1.1 and lower not iOS 6

any help? thanks on advance !

Comment: Well what is the question? It seems you have put all the answers in the question itself, followed by a "**right?**"

Comment: Why are you taking advantage of Reachability library if your app don't need to use internet?

Comment: So what does "Your app crashed on launch on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks" mean ? thanks for the answers.

Comment: It means your application crash on launch even if the device is connected to internet. They say that because they can't know if your application needs internet or not. So they tested the application with wifi off, it crashed then they tested the application with wifi on (thinking your application maybe need internet) but it crashed too. Why don't you update xcode ?

Comment: @Ashbay So it makes no sense to say that my app crashes on launch because wifi is turned off or on ! my app doesn't use internet connection it may be something else behind this weird crash. i'll update Xcode and see what happen. thanks Ashbay.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

- Build, Debug, and Test using a more recent version of Xcode, using the Simulator and Devices (with iOS 6)
- Remove the issues cited, and any other crashing issues
- Re-Submit

Reachability is not necessary. Your app will need to to handle errors gracefully (not crash/explode/leak/fall into a weird state).

Comment: Im developing an app that should work on iOS 4 and above, i just tested the app for the ios6 iPhone5 on the simulator, because im in Jordan, Middle East and iPhone5 didnt arrive to our country, dose the simulator work just like the actual device??, by the way when i test my app for the iPhone 5 i use the iphone simulator 6.0, retina 4.0

Comment: @Mutawe *"note that i tested my app on both simulator and actual devices all running iOS 5.1.1 and lower not iOS 6"* says you did not test it on iOS 6. that's a pain, when it is not available. if you cannot wait, you can hope that your beta testers can reproduce the issue and send the crash reports to you, unless you have a friend/colleague who has the device today and is willing to test it for you.